# How do I know timestamp when my Python app was deployed on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to know a value holding timestamp when my app was deployed on the GAE server. In runtime.

Surely I could generate some Python constant in the deployment script. But is there an easier and more correct way to reach the goal?

(I'd like not to use data store for that.)

Comment: What do you want to do with this timestamp?

Comment: I needed the timestamp to invalidate datastore cache entries older than that value. Probably I will choose to curl a special URL during deployment.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum, it's nice to be able to report the time of deployment to the client while testing and debugging. If nothing else just to rest easy that you're using the version you think you are.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap `appcfg.py` in a shell script. Before actually running `appcfg.py update`, save the current time, possibly adjusting for your time zone, if necessary, in a file that's marked as a resource. You can open and read that file from the deployed app.

Alternatively, have that script substitute the current time directly into code, obviating the need for a file open.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a GAE API that gives you access to the deploy timestamp.

The closest functionality is the [`CURRENT_VERSION_ID`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Environment) environment variable, but that only gives you access to the `version` specified in `app.yaml`, not timestamps.